# Using generic class in swift - KMM

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

In KMM project, I have a base view model which gets an state on its constructor which is a generic type. On Android side everything is correct but on iOS, the problem is that it can not automatically cast the class and it only works if I cast it manually. How to resolve this issue?

This is my base class:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<A : Any, S : Any, E : Any, R : Reducer<S>>(
private val effectHandler: EffectHandler<E>, initialState: S
) : KMMViewModel() {
abstract fun getActionHandlers(): Set<Pair<KClass<out A>, ActionHandler<*, S, E, R>>>

private val _state = MutableStateFlow(initialState)

@NativeCoroutinesState
val state: StateFlow<S> = _state.stateIn(
    viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), initialValue = initialState
)

@NativeCoroutinesState
val effect: Flow<E>
    get() = effectHandler.effects
}
```

This is my shared view model:

```
open class TestViewModel(testEffectHandler: TestEffectHandler): BaseViewModel<TestAction, TestState, TestEffect, TestReducer>(
    testEffectHandler, TestState("")
)
```

On Android side It works but on iOS side I have to cast the state manually to make it work. How should I define the generic class which will be automatically casted on Swift?

iOS side:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateViewModel private var viewModel : TestViewModel
    
    init(){
       let effectHandler = TestEffectHandler()
       _viewModel = StateViewModel(wrappedValue: .init(testEffectHandler: effectHandler))
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            
            **let str =  self.viewModel.state as? TestState**
            Text(str?.string ?? "empty")               

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Share some code with expected behavior and  how it actually works. Make sure you’ve read [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#generics)

Comment: I am sorry, I probably wasn't clear. Could you share iOS part, where unnecessary cast is happening as well?

Comment: @EvgenyK Thanks for your answer. I added the iOS part too

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.viewModel.state.value` then? Based on your code `viewModel.state` returns `StateFlow<TestState>`

Comment: @EvgenyK Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'

Comment: You shouldn't be defining variables inside view definition. Either mark `@ViewBuilder var body`, then it won't scream at you, but it's still a bad practice Better yet resolve your  `TestState` into `String` separately (eg. inside your viewModel, and pass it here as a string.

Comment: have you check how your `TestEffectHandler` looks like in generated ObjC header file? Most probably it has Any type from Swift. ObjC has some limitations when it comes to generics, not all kotlin constructs can be translated to ObjC. Check out [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#generics)